# Login for users with no folder redirection is virtually instantaneous, but login for users *with* folder redirection takes around 45 seconds

Tags: windows-7, windows-sbs-2003, folder-redirection, login

I have just configured a Windows 7 laptop for use on a SBS 2003 domain.

Everything works perfectly, except users with folder redirection have to wait approximately 45 seconds before they see their desktop after entering their credentials. This happens both when they are connected remotely to the main site via VPN and when offline.

By contrast, users with no folder redirection can log in virtually *instantaneously* (both with and without a network connection).

Is this additional delay to be expected? If not, what possible options do we have to reduce the logon times?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the folder-redirection option to relocate files?  The file relocation check probably involves some scanning of the disk.

Comment: I just checked the Group Policy - that particular setting is disabled. Where else can I turn? I'll try taking the laptop into the office later and seeing how quickly it logs on when on wireless and plugged straight into the LAN. Maybe that'll shed some light on this.

Comment: "connected remotely to the main site via VPN and when offline." Where are the redirected folders pointed to and what folders are being redirected? Logons with redirected folders connected to a remote file server is generally not recommended as it will have an impact on performance especially if you are redirecting the AppData folder. Having remote file servers and having the offline folders synched can also create a bottleneck.

Comment: The redirected folders are: My Pictures, My Documents and Desktop (*not* AppData). These are all being redirected to users' home drives on the server and are available offline for when the VPN connection isn't active. We've been using folder redirection for a year with the desktops with no problems. I'm now trying this on a shared, remote laptop to see what the user experience is like when using VPN instead of the LAN. So far it works brilliantly, the only inconvenience has been the 45-second logon time at the start of a session. So AppData is not being redirected. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It is expected to have such behavior over a WAN connection -which got confirmed by yourself in the answer you just posted (actually 45sec is not bad at all). have a look to this Technet [Article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/eb1202fb-0067-47a0-8430-147d7aa457da/folder-redirection-over-slow-link-gpo) for Folder Redirection over Slow Link GPO.

Comment: You're right. 45 seconds is not too bad! I was just wondering if there was something that could be done but apparently there isn't in this case.

Comment: I remember that there is a solution where it takes time only on first time then works faster with delta syncs only. And another solution that don't sync entire folders but get them on demand . . ...will post when I remember the details (promis)

Answer (score 0):

I went into the office where the domain controller is located and timed logging on (using an account *with* folder redirection) on both on the LAN and wirelessly.

Plugged into LAN: **6 seconds**

Wireless: **15 seconds**

Remotely from home via VPN: **45 seconds**

This is fine. I guess it's just a matter of the reduced bandwidth when logging on remotely.

The only way to remove this small logon delay would be to remove folder redirection, which would make the laptop much less useful to our users. Once logged on everything works perfectly, so we'll stick with the status quo. This provides 100% functionality, with the only downside being an extra 30 second delay when working when away from the main office.